# Android, Twitter's 'Authorize "AppName" to use your account ?' Screen appears every time

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have integrated Twitter login in my application, using Fabric (copied the code from fabric plugin). It works correctly, but every time this screen appears:

[image]

how can I get rid of this ? 
Here is the code I used:

Login Fragment:

```
private void onTwitterLogin() {
        twitterlogin.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                session = result.data;

                auth_token = session.getAuthToken();

                Twitter.getApiClient(session).getAccountService()
                        .verifyCredentials(true, false, new Callback<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User>() {

                            @Override
                            public void failure(TwitterException e) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void success(Result<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User> userResult) {

                                com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User tUser = userResult.data;
                                String twitterImage = tUser.profileImageUrl;

                                username = tUser.screenName;
                                name = tUser.name;

                                new TwitterLoginTask().execute(username, name, social_type);
                            }

                        });
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You don't have Twitter application \ninstalled in your device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    twitterlogin.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    FragmentManager fragment = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (fragment != null) {fragment.findFragmentByTag("LoginFragment").onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Astgh, I have same issue. Did you got any solution for this?